# [mod_rewrite]: Problems with redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a problem with rewriting urls. i have coded a small framework for myself because i don't need a full sized framework with lots of stuff for my projects. I defined the general behavior like zend framework:

Rewritten url: domain/controller/action

Real path: domain/index.php?ctrl=controller&act=action

Controller and action should be displayed instead of it $_GET named key. After controller and action if i add an infinite amount of additional parameters, it should be added as key/value like this:

domain/controller/action/key/value/key2/value2/key3/value3 ...

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1&act=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12&$13=$14 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1&act=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1&act=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1&act=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1&act2=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1&act=$2&$3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)+/([\w-]+)?$ index.php?ctrl=$1&act=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)+/?$ index.php?ctrl=$1 [L]
```

The page can only called with controller and action. If one of them is missing, the user will be redirected. I set headers for that:

```
// Redirects
if (!isset($_GET) || !isset($_GET['ctrl'])) {
    header('location: /index/index/');
}

if (!isset($_GET['act']) || (isset($_GET['act']) && empty($_GET['act']))) {
    header("location: /".$_GET['ctrl']."/index/");
}
```

It's dirty i know. Generally it works, but there are some problems that i can't solve:

1. if i try to call the webapp with domain/ the page can't be displayed or i will be redirected to google with the search "domain/". If i type domain/controller/action it works.
2. If i add a trailing slash after the action, it ends up with 404. It should be the same behavior like without the slash at end.
3. If i add a slash before the path in header('location:... it works for the following pattern: domain/controller. It will be redirected to domain/controller/action (in this case controller/index).

But if i try domain/ it results in 404.

Without slash before:

domain/controller/ results in domain/controller/controller/action but domain/ will be redirected correctly to  domain/index/index

What am i missing? :(

Thanks

Tyr

Comment: Ugh, please parse the URL in your PHP code and simply forward all requests to your PHP file instead of using such ugly URLs... Also, simply mapping querystring params including their names into path segments will not give you very clean URLs...

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "not very clean" urls, but "domain/user/edit/id/3" looks very clean for me

Comment: Take this question's url as an example. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974343/mod-rewrite-problems-with-redirecting` is nice, but with your system it would be e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/id/25974343/title/mod-rewrite-problems-with-redirecting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot this:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^yoururl.com/ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://yoururl.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

This code needs to go under:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Thanks. I was unsure to add the url into the .htaccess file, but it seems unavoidable. It works now.

Comment: Well the htaccess needs to know from where to rewrite.. That's why the url is a must..